# What is Python's "Namespace" object?

Tags: python

I know what namespaces are. But when running

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('bar')
parser.parse_args(['XXX']) # outputs:  Namespace(bar='XXX')
```

What kind of object is `Namespace(bar='XXX')`? I find this totally confusing.

Reading the argparse docs, it says "Most ArgumentParser actions add some value as an attribute of the object returned by parse_args()".  Shouldn't this object then appear when running `globals()`? Or how can I introspect it?

Comment: AFAIK, it's a dictionary-like object whose class is called `Namespace`. It has nothing to do with global or local namespace

Comment: "Shouldn't this object then appear when running globals()" huh? No, why do you think that would be true?

Comment: It's just the thing that `parse_args` returns. Most of the time, you just access the instance attributes it sets. Aside from a few niceties, you could basically define it as `class Namespace: pass`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have some confusion about how to actually introspect what Python is doing; just as if I were to assign a variable, e.g. `x=2`, then `x` would appear in `globals()` with value `2` I kind of expected some objects that were created "behind the scenes" to also appear in globals. But feel free to correct me, if that is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't appear in `globals()` because you didn't assign the return value of `parser.parse_args` to a global variable. If you write `args = parser.parse_args(['XXX'])`, then `globals()['args']` is the `Namespace` object.

Comment: As a general rule, functions to not inject names to any scope; only assignments do that.

Comment: @chepner Ok this general rule makes sense. Though I'm still a bit confused by the fact that it has a "nice name", instead of being something like `<function __main__.testfunction(n)>`. All I ever saw to obtain this way is something within brackets `<...>`.

Comment: One of the things the `Namespace` class provides is a `__repr__` function that produces the nice representation. You can see the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py#L1287) for yourself. (Note that the `__repr__` is inherited from `_AttributeHolder`, which acts as a base class for serveral classes defined in `argparse`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Samwise's answer is very good, but let me answer the other part of the question.

> Or how can I introspect it?

Being able to introspect objects is a valuable skill in any language, so let's approach this as though `Namespace` is a completely unknown type.

```
>>> obj = parser.parse_args(['XXX']) # outputs:  Namespace(bar='XXX')
```

Your first instinct is good. See if there's a `Namespace` in the global scope, which there isn't.

```
>>> Namespace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Namespace' is not defined
```

So let's see the actual type of the thing. The `Namespace(bar='XXX')` printer syntax is coming from a `__str__` or `__repr__` method somewhere, so let's see what the type *actually* is.

```
>>> type(obj)
<class 'argparse.Namespace'>
```

and its module

```
>>> type(obj).__module__
'argparse'
```

Now it's a pretty safe bet that we can do `from argparse import Namespace` and get the type. Beyond that, we can do

```
>>> help(argparse.Namespace)
```

in the interactive interpreter to get detailed documentation on the `Namespace` class, all with no Internet connection necessary.

Comment: Ohhh, this is really nice, just on my level of knowledge :). +1

Answer (score 5):

It's simply a container for the data that `parse_args` generates.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace

> This class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a readable string representation.

Just do `parser.parse_args(...).bar` to get the value of your `bar` argument.  That's all there is to that object.  Per the doc, you can also convert it to a dict via `vars()`.

The symbol `Namespace` doesn't appear when running `globals()` because you didn't import it individually.  (You can access it as `argparse.Namespace` if you want to.)  It's not necessary to touch it at all, though, because you don't need to instantiate a `Namespace` yourself.   I've used argparse many times and until seeing this question never paid attention to the name of the object type that it returns -- it's totally unimportant to the practical applications of argparse.

Comment: Great answer too! I agree I don't need to touch it, I am just bothered that here is  something new in terms of "behavior" that I don't understand. I'm actually still confused  by `argparse.Namespace` means. If I have an object, with the dot I can access and attribute or a method. If I have a module, with an attribute I can access something from that module, so that means `Namespace` is something that is defined there (and it indeed is, I checked it). But now I'm confused: If it is already defined in that module, how can `parse_args` modify it?

Comment: `parse_args` creates and returns an *instance* of the `Namespace` class; it doesn't modify a central `Namespace` object.

Answer (score 3):

[`Namespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py#L1287) is basically just a bare-bones class, on whose instances you can define attributes, with a few niceties:

- A nice `__repr__`
- Only keyword arguments can be used to instantiate it, preventing "anonymous" attributes.
- A convenient method to check if an attribute exists (`foo in Namespace(bar=3)` evaluates to `False`)
- Equality with other `Namespace` instances based on having identical attributes and attribute values. (E.g. ,`Namespace(foo=3, bar=5) == Namespace(bar=5, foo=3)`)

Instances of `Namespace` are returned by `parse_args`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('bar')
args = parser.parse_args(['XXX'])

assert args.bar == 'XXX'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was also really insightful +1 :)